# Sequence of HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, http, web, httpwebrequest

I am currently in the process of automating a web interface for administrating users of an FTP.

I am trying to do this with HttpWebRequest, i have one call that logs me on the site and the second call is supose to add a new user for the FTP access.

I have tried my two urls in the browser and they work, they end up creating a user.

```
string login = "https://www.ftpsite.net/./panel/index.php?txvUsername=myaccount&txvPassword=myPassword&submitButton=Login";
```

this gets me logged in when i enter it in the browser address bar.

the second call to create a user is as follows.

```
string createUser = "https://www.ftpSite.net/panel/ftpsites/updatelogin?login_id=&login=toto123&realname=realnametoto&homedir=root&passwd=superpassword11&expdate=01-01-2100&neverExpire=on&quota_value=0&quota_unit=GB&group_id=0&status=on&ftp=on&filelist=on&ftp_download=on&http=on&web_filelist=on&web_download=on&email=";
```

This creates a user when i enter  it in the browser's address bar if it follows the one that logs us in.

My problem is that i am trying to do this using HttpWebRequest and without success. I can get myself logged in but when i try to create the user it seems to return a "bad" error code saying i have created too many users already which isnt the case since i can create more after that call. Here is the code i use with HtttpRequest

```
        _datCookie = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(login);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = _datCookie;

        WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        referer = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;

        Stream requestStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(requestStream);
        _datCookie = httpWebRequest.CookieContainer;
        response.Close();



        httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(createUser);
        httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = _datCookie;
        httpWebRequest.Referer = referer;
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


        response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        requestStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        streamReader = new StreamReader(requestStream);


        webBrowser.DocumentText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        response.Close();
```

What i caught and tried to imitate without success [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL7bc.jpg).

Comment: If your error is from the FTP site, then you're going to need to look at that.  It's probably not anything wrong with your requests.   Is this a site you control, or is it a third-party ftp site?

Comment: Its a third party site, i think the problem is in the request because if i write the url and query string in the browser's address bar it works.

Comment: Please take fiddler, and analize you request from browser and from your http web request. End service doesn't know how you generated request unless there is difference in them. It should be post request with fake user id and all other params, such as content length, content-type etc etc.  Please let me know what was the result.

Comment: Fiddler does not catch the login post for some reason.

Comment: You may want to include your fiddler in your question too

Comment: I've got fiddler to work on my calls. What information should i post about the Request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Are you sure they should be POST requests? The URLs seem to have all of the fields in the query-string, which suggests they should be GET requests instead.</del>

Based on the Fiddler screen-shot, you need to make a POST request with the fields in the body, not the query-string:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();

// Request 1 : Login
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.ftpsite.net/./panel/index.php");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;

string postData = "txvUsername=myaccount&txvPassword=myPassword&submitButton=Login";
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
using (Stream bod = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   body.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
}

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string referer = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;

// Request 2 : Create user
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.ftpSite.net/panel/ftpsites/updatelogin");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;

postData = "login_id=&login=toto123&realname=realnametoto&homedir=root&passwd=superpassword11&expdate=01-01-2100&neverExpire=on&quota_value=0&quota_unit=GB&group_id=0&status=on&ftp=on&filelist=on&ftp_download=on&http=on&web_filelist=on&web_download=on&email=";
postBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
using (Stream bod = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   body.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
}

response = request.GetResponse();
requestStream = response.GetResponseStream();
streamReader = new StreamReader(requestStream);
webBrowser.DocumentText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
```

Comment: When i checked with Firebug its a Post request, i just dont know how to pass the params otherwise.

Comment: @dr-denis-mccraclejizz: If you're seeing a POST request in Firebug, that suggests it's an AJAX request initiated by the page you've loaded. If that's the case, you'll need to look at reproducing *that* request from your code.

Comment: @dr-denis-mccraclejizz: The problem is that the request you're issuing with the `HttpWebRequest` doesn't seem to be the request which creates the user. Based on your description, when you open the URL in your browser, a script on the page is issuing a second request, and it's *that* request which creates the user.

Comment: I added a screenshot of fiddler.

Comment: Ah, OK. It needs to be a POST request with the fields in the body. I'll update my answer with the relevant code.

Comment: Worked, Thanks alot ! Can you explain what i was doing wrong ?

Comment: You were passing the parameters in the query-string rather than the body of the request. http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod